# rsync from system A to system D through 2 bridges

Tags: networking, ssh, port, rsync

I would like to rsync from system A to system D through two intermediate bridges

A-> B -> C -> D

I have found these instructions:

http://toddharris.net/blog/2005/10/23/rsyncing-through-an-ssh-tunnel/

In particular I would like to use method 2, because I do have passwords and I don't know how to start rsync daemon.

I was thinking to do the following:

on system A

```
 Host system_B
 HostName localhost
 Port 2222
 HostKeyAlias system_B
 User system_B_user
```

on system B:

```
 Host system_C
 HostName localhost
 Port 22
 HostKeyAlias system_C
 User system_C_user
```

on system C:

```
 Host system_D
 HostName localhost
 Port 22
 HostKeyAlias system_D
 User system_D_user
```

and then opening tunnels:

on system A

```
ssh -fN -l system_B_user -L 2222:system_C:22 system_B
```

on system C

```
ssh -fN -l system_C_user -L 22:system_D:22 system_C
```

and running rsync from system A

The problem is:

1. I don't want to break anything
2. There must be a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried?:

```
rsync -azvu --exclude-from='./exclude.txt' -e 'ssh -p PORTNUMBER' user@host:/PATH/TOREMOTE/FILE/ORFOLDER/ /PATH/TO/LOKAL/FILEORFOLDER;
```